# crafting a TypeScript type with several specific "rules"

Tags: typescript, validation, types

I'm starting learning TypeScript as I would like to make my app more solid regarding its data.  That's its purpose, no ?

I would like to know if it's possible to define a type with very specific properties: it should be

- an object
- containing zero or one properties
- each key should be an URI
- each value should be an URI

Is that possible with TypeScript, and if yes, how ?
If not, what should I use to build such logic ?

Thanks !

Comment: How would you propose detecting if a string is a URI?  There is no built-in type for that, so you'd have to describe what you mean.  But before you answer that: could you please provide a [mre] of a use case with explicit code?  Like, are you going to be writing `const obj: MyObjType = { "https://example.com": "https://example.org" }` which is known at compile time or are you going to be writing `const obj: MyObjType = getObjFromSomeRuntimeSource()` which is only known at runtime?  And how would you  *use* a value of that type?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript type-safety is compile time only. In runtime it doesn't validate anything. Take a look at e.g. https://github.com/typestack/class-validator

Comment: Seems nice ! So, for what I want, I have to use classes, not types ?

Comment: You can use types with class-validator as well. Nest.js documentation on validation describes it nicely https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation. Typescript doesn't check types at runtime. So if you have user input and say it's a number in typescript, user can just send string, nothing will prevent them from doing that. If you have user input objects and want to validate them using class-validator, you can use `plainToClass` from class-transformer. Something like `validate(plainToClass(YourValidationClass, yourObject));`

Comment: I just found this, which seems great too !  [ObjectModel](https://github.com/sylvainpolletvillard/ObjectModel) - 
_Strong Dynamically Typed Object Modeling for JavaScript_